# Structure theorem for non connected graded Hopf algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras

Let $V^{\bullet}$ be a graded vector space over a field of char $0$. Assume that $V^{i}=0$ for $i<1$. Then the tensor algebra has the structure of a connected cocommutative Hopf algebra and in particular its Lie algebra of primitive $P(T(V))$ is naturally ismorphic to the free Lie algebra. This result is a consequence of the structure theorem for connected Hopf algebras: given a connected Hopf algebra $H$ then
$$ H\cong U(P(H)), $$
where $U$ is the universal enveloping algebra. Here my questions

1) Is the connectess of $H$ a necessary requirement for the structure theorem? Do you know some counter examples?

2) Assume $V^{i}=0$ for $i<0$, then the tensor algebra $T(V)$ is again a graded cocommutative Hopf algebra but it is no longer connected. Let $L(V)$ be the graded free Lie algebra on $V^{\bullet}$, are $P(T(V))$ and $L(V)$ isomorphic?

Comment: The structure theorem you are alluding to undoubtedly imposes additional assumptions beyond connectedness (e.g., cocommutativity of H, ground field is of characteristic zero). Perhaps you could clarify precisely what those additional hypotheses are. If you drop any one of those hypotheses then you are likely to find counterexamples. For example, the Drinfeld-Jimbo "quantum groups" are examples of non-commutative, non-cocommutative Hopf algebras. These can be considered as trivially graded Hopf algebras (grading concentrated in degree 0).

Comment: Ups you have right! My situation is with a fieldd of charachteristic zero and with a cocommutative Hopf algebra. I will edit now.

Comment: A group algebra of a finite group is a cocommutative Hopf algebra, but not connected (unless the group is trivial) and not isomorphic to the universal enveloping algebra of its primitives (again, unless the group is trivial).

Comment: To question 2), I think the answer is "yes". Unless your definition of $L\left(V\right)$ depends on the grading on $V$, you could just redefine the grading to have $V^1 = V$, and then $P\left(T\left(V\right)\right) \cong L\left(V\right)$ would hold due to the connectedness of the new grading.

Comment: Cross-posted (after 4 hours only) from MathSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643041/